# rsync but keep destination ownership without setting to source ownership

Tags: linux, rsync, sudo

I've got some files which I would like to sync to a linux server. Only problem is it resets the ownership and group to the current user and group.

Unfortunately the options --owner, --group, and --archive are somewhat unworkable because the source is a windows machine. (it's ownership doesn't make sense on the server)

Any way to keep destination ownership unchanged?

Command i'm using (minimal example):

`rsync SRC $remote:DEST`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `--inplace` option:

`rsync --inplace SRC $remote:DEST`

Correctly does not change destination ownership (or permissions), regardless of what the source's are.

Documentation:

> --inplace
>
> This option changes how rsync transfers a file when the file's data
> needs to be updated: instead of the default method of creating a new
> copy of the file and moving it into place when it is complete, rsync
> instead writes the updated data directly to the destination file.
>
> [Warning: May cause issues when changing files that are in-use]

For full details see rsync [docs page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync#content:%7E:text=%2D%2Dinplace,-This).

Answer (score 1):

Try `rsync -azvr something somwhere:/location/`.

Answer (score 1):

Identify the user and group on the remote end. Example user "user1" and group "user1".

1. add "--chown user1:user1" to your rsync command
2. Alternatively if your version of rsync does not support that, on the remote, run "chown -R user1:user1 *" inside the highest folder of your destination file tree and this will recursively reown everything to user1. (WARNING: this syntax also changes everything in the current folder)